# Watching a QImage during single-stepping

Tags: debugging, qt, qimage

I'm debugging a huge Qt app with hundreds of classes, messy code, etc.  While tracking down a bug, I want to single-step in gdb (kdbg, ddd, whatever) while watching what gets drawn into a QImage using a QPainter that's carried about from method to method.  Somewhere, it's doing being given bad information.  Normally all I can get is the final QImage written to a .png file.

Is there some way to see what the image is in a QImage when stopped in a debugger?

BTW, this is using Qt4.3, which is kinda old but we're stuck with for now.  If a newer Qt offers some advantage, I have ways to hack with it (as well as others seeing this question may have the latest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's one of the examples in the [Peek and Poke, Vol. 3](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/04/22/peek-and-poke-vol-3/) article on [Qt Labs blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/).

Comment: Somewhat interesting, but I'm not using QtCreator, and I'm not sure exactly what I would do even if I were.   We're all-linux with a  cmake build system, command line and each person's favorite text editor. I use kdbg as a front end for gdb.

Comment: Did anyone actually try this and get it to work? It doesn't work for me with Creator 3.2.82. I don't see an image anywhere.